# Filter remote address by URL in Tomcat6.0

Tags: tomcat6

I would like to filter remote ip address entering with url(/aa/*).
I use Tomcat6.0.
I would like to know how to configure filter configuration in web.xml of Tomcat3.6.
Please support sample if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<filter>
<filter-name>RequestIDFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>x.y.z.RequestIdFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>RequestIDFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/aa/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```